# VSCode same Snippet with different placeholder

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor, placeholder, code-snippets, textmate

```
"test": {
        "prefix": "test",
        "body": "${1:hello} ${1:world}"
    }
```

Expected Result:

```
hello world
```

Current Result:

```
hello hello
```

I am trying to create snippet with same index and different placeholder but second placeholder change to first one when snippet called.

Case Scenario:

If I remove `hello` then `world` should be removed as well and If I don't change default `hello` then tabstop should goto next `world`. Then If I change `world`, `hello` shouldn't be effected.

This work great with Atom [See this youtube video](https://youtu.be/SFY-5yMV634) but not with vscode !!!

Comment: You only have one tabstop so there is no going to the "next" `world`.  I would say that using two different default placeholders for the same tabstop is unsupported.  I could be wrong.  Can you make animated gif showing the Atom behaviour?

Comment: https://youtu.be/SFY-5yMV634

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself at last, here it is,

```
"test": {
        "prefix": "test",
        "body": [
            "${1:hello} I am good",
            "how are ${1/^(?!\\s*$).+/world/}",
        ]
    },
```

$1 is `hello` and replace second clone with `world` which is also at $1, if no `hello` then no `world` as well.